# How do I specify an App groups in the nativescript application (for iOS)

Tags: nativescript

I'm developing an application with Share Extension in nativescript.
The Share Extension is developed using XCode and has an App Groups specified.
How do I specify an App Groups on the main application without the need to enter the XCode every build?

Comment: You may do it once with Xcode, copy the entitlements file to app resources so it will be copied back to platforms folder on subsequent builds you do.

Comment: The share extension has the App Groups. The question is how to set this also to the main application that recompiled every build?